# All inclusive resorts - Are they worth it compared to using hotels of the same comfort class

Tags: beaches, caribbean, resorts

We are looking to do a trip to the Caribbean around March of next year and are trying to decide if an all-inclusive resort (such as Sandals) would be a good experience. Our trip budget (including flights) is about $7k.

Has any of you traveled in the same area using 'normal' hotels as well as all inclusive and which worked out cheaper, using the same class of hostels?

And is there a difference between the cheaper and more expensive resorts compared to hotels in the same price brackets?

Comment: Their mere existence indicated that they facilitate a certain audience. Weather they are worth it depends on your personal preference, making it a hard to answer question.

Comment: Additionally, there are a range of packages and a range of resorts to choose from; some will be like a mid-range Hilton and others will be like the Waldorf Astoria.

Comment: Let's start with questions in order: Yes, Depends and Depends, How much money do you have?  All in All this question is not answerable because it depends most heavily on your budget and place where you want to go and what you're looking to do and most importantly asks for an opinion from the person answering.  I would suggest reviewing [Help Center](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help) and rephrasing.

Comment: [An Asset Is Worth What A Buyer Will Pay When You Try To Sell](http://seekingalpha.com/instablog/4596961-joseph-stuber/1814801-an-asset-is-worth-what-a-buyer-will-pay-when-you-try-to-sell). Will someone pay the price? Then it's worth it--to them.

Comment: Welcome to Travel Stack Exchange Mike. I guess you must be new to Stack Exchange though since you don't seem to know it's different to a forum in that opinions and suggestions are not supported. Stack Exchange needs questions that have specific answers. For me no resort is ever worth it. But obviously hundreds of thousands of other pople have a different opinion. I can only suggest you try to find a regular travel forum if you can't rephrase this as a question with an objective answer.

Comment: I tried to reword the question such that it fits within the guidelines for the site.

Answer (score 2):

The main advantage of an all-inclusive resort is you know the cost and you needn't spend anything extra. This may suit certain types of budget conscious travellers who aren't intending on straying too far from the resort.

If it turns out you don't like the resort food, then there may not be much you can do about it. Check in advance for positive reviews in this regard before committing to a resort.

If you are intending on doing some sight seeing, it isn't always convenient to travel back to the resort to eat.

If you like trying out other places to eat while you are there, an all-inclusive resort might not be the best value.